# select in a for loop deadlock's

Tags: go

https://play.golang.org/p/FyIUPkwq0R

Why does the following deadlock?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)
var quit chan bool
var buffer chan string

func main() {
        buffer = make(chan string)
    quit = make(chan bool)
    go func() {
        i:=0
        for {
            select {
            case <- quit:
                fmt.Println("Bye!")
                return
            default:
                fmt.Println(<-buffer)
            }
            i++
            fmt.Println(i)
        }
    }()
    buffer <- "Go!"
    quit <- true        // This line dead locks
    //buffer <- "Hello" // When I do this instead it works?
    //quit <- true      // Also when I don't quit it still exit's?
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code isn't guaranteed to work properly. You might get lucky, but apparently you've been getting unlucky. You might get lucky and the following might happen:

Let's say we have two goroutines, A and B, where A is the goroutine running `main` and B is the goroutine running the anonymous function. The following might happen:

- B: Execute `select`; there's nobody writing on the `quit` channel, so execute the `default` case
- B: Execute `<-buffer`, so begin blocking, waiting for somebody to write to `buffer`
- A: Write "Go!" to `buffer`
- B: Receive "Go!" and print it. Continue looping.
- A: Write true to `quit`
- B: Execute `select`; A is trying to write to `quit`, so execute that case. Print "Bye!" and return
- A: Since write has finished, continue and return from `main`

However, this isn't guaranteed to happen. In particular, after reading from `buffer`, B might keep executing, execute the `select`, and fall into the `default` case before A has a chance to write to `quit`. That's what's probably happening, and would look like this:

- B: Execute `select`; there's nobody writing on the `quit` channel, so execute the `default` case
- B: Execute `<-buffer`, so begin blocking, waiting for somebody to write to `buffer`
- A: Write "Go!" to `buffer`
- B: Receive "Go!" and print it. Continue looping
- B: Execute `select`; there's nobody writing on the `quit` channel, so execute the `default` case
- B: Execute `<-buffer`, so begin blocking, waiting for somebody to write to `buffer`
- A: Write true to `quit`, so begin blocking, waiting for somebody to read from `quit`

Now both A and B are blocked, and since there are no other goroutines in the system, no event can ever unblock either of them, so the system is stuck.

### Solution

One way of fixing this would be to make it so that goroutine B reads from the `buffer` as one of the `select` cases instead of inside a select case. This way, the `select` will simply block until either channel becomes available for an action, and your code will behave as you probably wanted it to:

```
select {
    case <-quit:
        fmt.Println("Bye!")
        return
    case str := <-buffer:
        fmt.Println(str)
}
```

See it [here](https://play.golang.org/p/PICrSxk-Kl) on the Go Playground.

Note, however, that since the `main` goroutine is returning as soon as it writes to the `quit` channel, and the entire Go program exits as soon as that happens, you may (and probably will) get unlucky and `fmt.Println("Bye!")` will not execute before the program quits.

Answer (score 2):

Change the select default clause to

```
        default:
            fmt.Println("waiting on <-buffer")
            fmt.Println(<-buffer)
```

to see what's going on.

The issue is that the goroutine executes the default branch in the select before `main` executes `quit <- true`.

The goroutine blocks at `fmt.Println(<-buffer)` and the `main` function blocks at `quit <- true`.

To prevent the deadlock, receive in the case statement:

```
        select {
        case <-quit:
            fmt.Println("Bye!")
            return
        case msg := <-buffer:
            fmt.Println(msg)
        }
```

[playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/d4Ml1Aq41j)

Comment: Ok thanks, need a few minutes to think about it, I am not that smart :D

Comment: Got it :) PS can you maybe also add that if main exit's first, the quit channel on the go routine doesn't matter because it gets killed anyway. I also forgot about that :D

Answer (score 0):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

var quit chan bool
var buffer chan string

func main() {
    buffer = make(chan string)
    quit = make(chan bool)

    go func() {
        i := 0
        for {
            select {
            case <-quit:
                fmt.Println("Bye!")
                return
            case v := <-buffer:
                fmt.Println(v)
            default:
                // 这里也可能 block
                // fmt.Println(<-buffer)
            }

            i++
            fmt.Println(i)
        }
    }()

    buffer <- "Go!"
    quit <- true // This line dead locks
    //buffer <- "Hello" // When I do this instead it works?
    //quit <- true      // Also when I don't quit it still exit's?
}
```